# Turning off history listbox in Tkinter file dialogs

Tags: tkinter, dialog

I wrote a word processor which normally saves the last path on closing, but with a "no tracing" option, which doesn't. My problem is that the Tkinter file dialogs for opening and saving files (actually native Windows 10 tools) both feature a cute history listbox (click on the "V "on the right end of the file name requester), which defeats the purpose of my "no tracing" option. I couldn't find any switch to turn it off in the Tkinter documentation. Is there a workaround solution?

Comment: Short answer is not. There is no way to change this behaviour of the file dialog. It's something built in to windows. You could create your own file dialog.

Comment: Thank you. One funny observation : I get exactly the same history listbox content (* . * ) with OpenOffice Text, even though I rarely use OO... MS Word history listbox shows only Word files (*.docx or another extension). Obviously, the Tkinter file requester is a native Windows feature.